# Use {select} format (format.js) with polymers app-localize-behavior

Tags: localization, polymer, polymer-1.0, messageformat.js

I'm doing some trials with Polymers app-localize-behavior, and I'm having a hard time to find some clear documentation regarding how to use format.js's {select} Format  found [here](http://formatjs.io/guides/message-syntax/).

The app-localization-behavior [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-localize-behavior) says : 

**"Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior supports the same message-syntax of format.js, in its entirety;"**

But for example in the polymer docs they pass the arguments as strings:

```
{{localize('hello', 'Batman')}}
```

and in format.js docs not:

```
I have {numCats, number} cats.
```

Now the issue I'm facing is how to use the {select} Format.

The format.js [docs](http://formatjs.io/guides/message-syntax/) says to use it like this:

```
{gender, select,
male {He}
female {She}
other {They}
} will respond shortly.
```

so I did this in my template:

```
{{localize(wir, select,
            wir {we}
            ich {i}
           )
}}
```

locales.json :

```
{
"en" : {
         "i" : "I",
         "we" : "we"        
       },
"fr" : { 

         "i" : "je",
         "we" : "nous"
       },
"de" : {
         "i" : "ich",
         "we" : "wir"
       }
}
```

The language is set by default to french `"fr"`, so I expect to get "nous" as output, but instead the full `{{localize(etc..)}}` is displayed on screen.

The last I did, was trying to pass everything as string or just some of the arguments (all combinations) but this all doesn't helps.

Did anyone faced the same issue or can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here pls?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`localize` usage**

- The arguments to `localize` must be quoted if they're string literals, as in:

  ```
  {{localize('hello', 'Batman')}}
  ```

  Otherwise, they're treated as properties. For example, if you had a `name` property that contained `Batman`, you would use:

  ```
  {{localize('hello', name)}}
  ```
- The first `localize` argument is a key into the language dictionary (defined either in your element's `resources` property, or in an external file loaded by your element, such as `locales.json`)
- All `localize` arguments after the first are passed directly to [`intl-messageformat`](https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat#formatvalues-method).

This string:

```
{gender, select,
male {He}
female {She}
other {They}
} will respond shortly.
```

...is a message format, which must be defined as a value in the language dictionary. This example shows the dictionary defined in a `resources` property with a key of `response`:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    resources: {
      value: function() {
        return {
          'en': { 'response': `{gender, select,
                                male {He}
                                female {She}
                                } will respond shortly.` },
          'fr': { 'response': `{gender, select,
                                male {Il}
                                female {Elle}
                                } répondra prochainement.` }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then, in your element's template, you would use `localize` as follows:

```
<div>Message: {{localize('response', 'gender', 'female')}}</div>
```

where:

- **`'response'`**: the lookup key into the language dictionary
- **`'gender'`**: the key of the `{select}`
- **`'female'`**: the selector of the `{select}`

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">

  <!-- Polygit can't find intl-messageformat.min.js, so we're importing
       it here for app-localize-behavior. Don't use this in your apps! -->
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat/v1.3.0/dist/intl-messageformat-with-locales.min.js"></script>

  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-toggle-button on-change="_switchLanguage">Language: {{language}}</paper-toggle-button>
      <paper-toggle-button on-change="_switchGender">Gender: {{gender}}</paper-toggle-button>
      <div>Message: {{localize('response', 'gender', gender)}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          behaviors: [
            Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior
          ],
          properties: {
            gender: {
              type: String,
              value: "male"
            },
            language: {
              value: 'en'
            },
            resources: {
              value: function() {
                return {
                  'en': {
                    'response': "{gender, select,\
                                  male {He}\
                                  female {She}\
                                  } will respond shortly."
                  },
                  'fr': {
                    'response': "{gender, select,\
                                  male {Il}\
                                  female {Elle}\
                                  } répondra prochainement."
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          _switchGender: function() {
            this.gender = this.gender === 'male' ? 'female' : 'male';
          },
          _switchLanguage: function() {
            this.language = this.language === 'fr' ? 'en' : 'fr';
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dXpjGR?editors=1010)

Comment: The code snippet creates an HTMLImport error. "http://stacksnippets.net/js"////// However, It does work when I test it locally